# What is this low voltage power supply leading into the wall?

Tags: electrical

I found this in the back-corner of our second-floor closet:

[image: power supply]

[image: unplugged]

Presumably this is not to code. Has anyone seen anything like this before, or have any ideas what it's for?  Unplugging it doesn't seem to have broken anything, and there aren't any small electronics on any of the nearby walls.

Comment: code isn't too concerned with low voltage wiring, are you sure it's a problem?

Comment: Well, the missing faceplate certainly isn't Code! As to the low-voltage side of things, can you get us clear shots (or a readout) of the printing on the low-voltage wiring? That's the determinant as to whether the LV wiring is of the proper type to be used in a wall to begin with...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like the power supply for an old alarm system.

Comment: concur with @freshop, You might have the remnants of the old system hanging in a nearby closet up high or down low, possibly under a panel cover.

Comment: There is an old alarm system downstairs, so this is probably correct.

Answer (score 8):

Nobody mentioned door-bell.
Many electrical doorbells use a AC transformer with output anywhere in the 5 to 20V range.
9 and 12V AC are most common.

Comment: Agreed - easy test is to plug the PSU then go test the doorbell.

Comment: @Criggie Several years ago my father janked several yards of thin 2-lead wire from behind the drywall when he re-modeled his hallway. He thought it was old alarm-system wiring, no longer used. It wasn't until several days later when someone was at the door he realized he destroyed the door-bell. Of course the walls had been re-done by then. Now he has a wireless door-bell :-)

Comment: Doorbell transformers are generally 16vac

Comment: @batsplatsterson That is very location specific I think. Here they almost exclusively 12 Vac and the few that are not are 9 Vac. Some very old ones (30+ years) are 8 or 10 Vac. I have never seen a 16 Vac.

Comment: @Tonny - where is that?

Comment: @batsplatsterson Europe, Belgium, Netherlands and UK to be more exact.

Comment: Well, the outlet in the picture is clearly a US-style, and OP's profile seems to imply that as well.  (Could be Canada, but it'd be the same thing there.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Just had a Skype call with my cousin in Vancouver. I asked him about his door-bell and he actually went to check. It is 12 Vac.

Comment: In the USA, 16VAC is the most common but can also be lower (8VAC) so you dont get "buzzed" or 24VAC (uncommon), this is what I have https://www.heath-zenith.com/products/doorbell-transformer-sl-130?taxon_id=9

Answer (score 2):

I agree it's likely this is an alarm system power supply, I know Honeywell had some 9VAC panels and likely others.

Believe it or not it may be code compliant, the rules for class 2 wiring are pretty loose.  It's not really workmanship anyone would brag about but it's a pretty common hack.

If the cable is suitably rated CL2 or better it's compliant.  However it looks like a zipcord which is not likely rated for installation inside walls on class 2 circuits.  However, at 9VAC, it's not much of a hazard.

Comment: Note that even if it's nominally 9V, there's absolutely nothing there that instills confidence that a short on that red cable won't get 1000A going through it. The irony would be if it were supplying power to a /fire/ alarm, particularly if its standby batteries were long dead.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd the only way a transformer of that size could supply 1000A would be if the input were shorted to the output.  And then you'd have even bigger problems.

Comment: I think @MarkMorganLloyd may have been thinking about a short from a 120V line to the low voltage line, like if a nail or screw were to pass through both of them.

Comment: Actually, I saw MADE IN CHINA and at that point ceased making any assumptions whatsoever regarding what's in the box.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Apparently nobody in the USA has been smart enough figure out that using *wood* as a structural material for house building, together with an insane electrical supply system that increases the likelihood of unwanted heat generation, might be the root cause of the problem. Nobody in Europe even worries about electrical fires (or arcane wiring codes) because they are so rare. Bricks and stones don't burn!

Comment: @alephzero I'm in Europe and proud of it. (Well actually I'm in the UK and that opens up a whole can of worms... but we still don't build our houses out of "lumber")

Comment: @alephzero, Course for horses. Brick houses around here (California) have a bad habit of falling down if the ground shakes a little bit.